# Java if and || issue

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean, jgrasp

I'm doing this little program, but unfortunately I ran into this issue..

```
  if (ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' || ccnString.charAt(0) != '3') { 
      System.out.println("The String entered does not fit any of the Credit card standards");
      System.exit(0);
  }
```

My program does not recognize if I put in any of the integers in my String.

However, if I delete my || and the last part, the if statement recognizes the first integer.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for AND, not OR.

Comment: Thing about *exactly* what you've specified. Pick different characters (e.g. `x`, `3`, `4`) and think about what each side of the `||` evaluates to.

Comment: can someone explain this? my program does not recognize if i put in any of the integers in my string. what does it mean? does it mean if we have 35 or 45 everthing is ok ? or we have to have 34 or 43?

Comment: @hobbs can you elucidate it more?

Comment: De Morgan struck again... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' || ccnString.charAt(0) != '3')
```

Is always `true`.

**Every character** is `!= '4'` or `!= '3'`

I guess you want `&&` instead.

Details:

The statement `A || B` is true if A is true or B is true (or both are true).

In your example, lets say that the first character is '4'.

A = `ccnString.charAt(0) != '4'` is false (4 != 4 is false)

B = `ccnString.charAt(0) != '3'` is true (3 != 4 is true)

So `A || B` is true because B is true.

Comment: I have difficulty to understand this. how this always true?

Comment: @KickButtowski A || B means if either A or B is true then the overall result is true, whereas A && B means the overall result is true only if both A and B is true

Comment: @KickButtowski: If the first character is '4' (which is the only way the first part will return `false`), then it is necessarily not equal to '3'.

Comment: @BobTheBuilder    so if we change != to ==, it is better?

Comment: It will show the error message if the string starts with 3 or starts with 4.

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to the many other answers that correctly state that you must use *and* (`&&`) instead of *or* (`||`).

You have been fooled by [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). They define how boolean expressions are negated.

In your example, the original expression that defines a valid user input is as follows:

```
validInput = userPressed3 or userPressed4
```

But as we are interested in invalid user input, this expression has to be negated:

```
not(validInput) = not(userPressed3 or userPressed4)
```

According to *De Morgan*, `not(A or B)` is equal to `not(A) and not(B)`. So we can also write:

```
not(validInput) = not(userPressed3) and not(userPressed4)
```

In other words: It's De Morgan's fault! ;)

Answer (score 2):

You probably want

```
if (ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' && ccnString.charAt(0) != '3') {
    System.out.println("The String entered does not fit any of the Credit card standards");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

This would give your error message only for Strings that don't start with `4` AND don't start with `3`.

Your original condition gives an error for any String that either doesn't start with `4` OR doesn't start with `3`, and since all Strings satisfy that condition, you'll always get your error message.

If you require additional conditions after the initial test, you can do :

```
if (ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' && ccnString.charAt(0) != '3') {
    System.out.println("The String entered does not fit any of the Credit card standards");
    System.exit(0);
} else if (ccnString.charAt(0) == '3' && ccnString.charAt(1) == '7') {
     // here you know that ccnString starts with 37
} else if (...) {
    ...
}
... add as many else ifs as you need ...
else {
    // default behavior if all previous conditions are false
}
```

Comment: that solved the issue.. but however I'm furthermore going to check in the same if statement if the first 2 digits are 37 as well. There will be flaws by doing && in this case wouldn't there?

Comment: @Avacay You can put the next condition in an else if () {} statement that follows the original if.

Comment: @Avacay answer posted, this is what you want

Comment: so 
   else if(ccnString.charAt(0) == '3' && ccnString.charAt(1) == '7') {}

Doesn't give me what i want.. i can still do like 67 and it echoes correct.. :(

Comment: @Avacay If you enter 67, the first condition (as in my answer) should give you an error message.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `&&` not `||`

```
ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' && ccnString.charAt(0) != '3'
```

Else `(ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' || ccnString.charAt(0) != '3'` always `true`

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ((ccnString.charAt(0) != '4' && ccnString.charAt(0) != '3')
                || (ccnString.charAt(0) == '3' && ccnString.charAt(1) == '7')) {
            System.out.println("The String entered does not fit any of the Credit card standards");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```